# SSL client cert authentication for only some URLs?

Tags: authentication, ssl

If I authenticate my clients using SSL client certs, is that necessarily a site-wide filter, or can I either require or not require authentication per-URL from within an application?  So I'd like

https://mysite.com/my_url doesn't care who the client is, just uses 'normal' https
https://mysite.com/my_sensitive_url requires that the client is using a valid client cert

I'm working in Ruby on Rails, but I'm interested in the general question of whether SSL client cert authentication is flexible enough for this.  I can imagine that a hand-written apache conf with different settings for different URLs could probably do it, but I'd really much rather define this kind of thing at the application level.

Comment: From practice: This can be done (on SSL level) by not requiring a client certificate. Then after the client sends the HTTP request with the URL, based on that the server can continue as is, or renegotiate the SSL connection and this time require ('want' or 'need') a client certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would (a) set the server to do authentication via SSL certificates; (b) set the server to to 'want' rather than 'need' SSL client authentication, and then (c) define access rules for the specific URLs or patterns that required the user to be logged in, and not for the others.

Comment: Just to expound on this... there's a problem that the server doesn't know if the client wants /my_url or /my_sensitive_url until after the SSL handshake has been completed, and thus the server doesn't know if a certificate is necessary until it's too late.  Part (b) of this answer solves this problem without requiring SSL renegotiation.