# IIS application - some Urls should require client ssl certificates and other don't ask for it

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, ssl, client-certificates

I have an IIS7-hosted, asp .Net application (written in c#).

Some of the app URLs need to be accessed with a client certificate, and some must be accessed without it.

This isn't a duplicate of  [This SA question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701389/ssl-client-cert-authentication-for-only-some-urls) because The setting the application to "accept client certificates" for all URLs causes some browsers (Android) present the user with a dialog to choose a client certificate, even though it isn't actually needed for these specific urls.

So I need 2 sets of Urls (let's say 2 Urls for simplicity) - one that IIS will **require** an SSL certificate and one url the will **not ask for** a certificate.

Is there any way to achieve this in IIS or do I have to split my application into 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually solved it by

1. Creating a virtual directory under my application for the URL that requires that no client certificate is negotiated.
2. Changed the client certificate setting in the ssl settings foe that virtual directory to "ignore".
3. The virtual directory points back to my application
4. Since the web config now is read twice (once for the virtual directory and once for the app), needed to make some settings idempotent (meaning - add a remove before an add for some web.config settings).
5. The main application ssl client certificate setting remained in the "accept" state.

Comment: Probably you could've used the location tag as in here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/29237456/220230

Answer (score 0):

In MVC there is an attribute you can add to your controller methods such as:

```
 [RequireHttps]
public ActionResult PageOne() {
     return this.View();
}

 public ActionResult PageTwo() {
    return this.View(); }
```

The first would require SSL, the second would not.

In WebForms you could create a httpModule that checks the url in the ApplicationBeginRequest method and redirects to the SSL page if required, but this would need to be on a page by page basis.

I do not think you can do this in IIS.  Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Seems like you are talking about server certificates whereas I was talking about client certificates.