# Can IIS require SSL client certificates without mapping them to a windows user?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, ssl, client-certificates

I want to be able to map SSL client certificates to ASP.NET Identity users.  I would like IIS to do as much of the work as possible (negotiating the client certificate and perhaps validating that it is signed by a trusted CA), but I don't want IIS to map the certificate to a Windows user.  The client certificate is passed through to ASP.NET, where it is inspected and mapped to an ASP.NET Identity  user, which is turned into a ClaimsPrincipal.

So far, the only way I have been able to get IIS to pass the client certificate through to ASP.NET is to enable `iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication` and set up a many-to-one mapping to a Windows account (which is then never used for anything else.)  Is there any way to get IIS to negotiate and pass the certificate through without this configuration step?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have to use the iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication. The client certificate is accessible in the HttpContext.

```
var clientCert = HttpContext.Request.ClientCertificate;
```

Either you enable RequireClientCertificate on the complete site or use a separate *login-with-clientcertificate* page.

Below is one way of doing this in ASP.NET MVC. Hopefully you can use parts of it to fit your exact situation.

1. First make sure you are allowed to set the SslFlags in web.config by turning on feature delegation.

[image: IIS - Feature delegation]

2. Make site accept (but not require) Client Certificates
   [image]
3. Set path to login-with-clientcertificate-page where client certificates will be required. In this case a User controller with a CertificateSignin action.
   [image: web.config]
4. Create a login controller (pseudo-code)

   ```
   [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
   [AllowAnonymous()]
   public ActionResult CertificateSignIn()
   {
       //Get certificate
       var clientCert = HttpContext.Request.ClientCertificate;

       //Validate certificate
       if (!clientCert.IsPresent || !clientCert.IsValid)
       {
           ViewBag.LoginFailedMessage = "The client certificate was not present or did not pass validation";
           return View("Index");
       }

       //Call your "custom" ClientCertificate --> User mapping method.
       string userId;
       bool myCertificateMappingParsingResult = Helper.MyCertificateMapping(clientCert, out userId);

       if (!myCertificateMappingParsingResult)
       {
           ViewBag.LoginFailedMessage = "Your client certificate did not map correctly";
       }
       else
       {
           //Use custom Membersip provider. Password is not needed!
           if (Membership.ValidateUser(userId, null))
           {
               //Create authentication ticket
               FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userId, false);
               Response.Redirect("~/");
           }
           else
           {
               ViewBag.LoginFailedMessage = "Login failed!";
           }
       }

       return View("Index");
   }
   ```

Comment: Yeah, I was mistaken about the cause of my not receiving the certificates in the HttpRequest.  It started working due to other changes, but this is a good answer, thanks for taking the time.

Comment: This does not ask or prompt for client certificate at all!, How do client pass the certificate to server?

Comment: @HirenDesai - "...This does not ask or prompt for client certificate at all..." : Note that my sample code above is for the server-side and not the client side. If your client is a browser it should prompt you for a certificate as long as a certificate from one of the server preferred issuers are available in the CurrentUser CertificateStore\My. If your client is something else you might have to select the certificate in code or configuration first depending on your framework.    "...How do client pass the certificate to server?..." : The is done as part of the protocol handshake.

Comment: @HirenDesai - Tell me more about your setup (os/framework/client/server) and i might provide some help.

Comment: @magnus - Yes, you were right, I have created same setup and it's working now. but the problem is, It throws errors such as: ERR_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_SIGNATURE_FAILED, ERR_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NO_PRIVATE_KEY and 403.16 when accessed from different computer.

Comment: @HirenDesai - 403.16 usually means that the issuer of the certificate you use on the other computer is not trusted. Put the issuer of the client certificate in the servers "LocalMachine\Trusted Root Authorities" certificate store. What type of client are you using?

Comment: "ERR_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NO_PRIVATE_KEY" means the certificate is not available. @magnus is correct; but it's not a trust issue - it's just in the wrong store.

Comment: great explanation! I have an issue strongly related with this: In my case, i have PKI authentication working perfectly with my intranet user certificates (anonymous enabled and everything else disabled on IIS), but as soon as I add the "authorization" tag to the web.config to grant access to determined user groups, the request is denied with the generic "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials." message. Any idea why? The group which I allow access is correct and the user belongs to it

Comment: @Carlos - are you mapping the ClientCertificate to a user using iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication or have you rolled your own solution like in my example above?

Comment: @magnus - Not really, The only thing thatI did is to enable iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication in IIS, nothing else. Am I missing something? What I would like to do is to map the client certificate (many different users belonging to a specific AD group) to enable the ASP.NET application check whether the client certificate sent by the browser belongs to a valid AD   user within a specific AD group. In IIS, I just enabled iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication but I did not specify anything on Many-to-one, one-to-one etc..