# Require client certificate only for a folder

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis, client-certificates

Currently my application is under a load balancer (NetScaler) and it does SSL Offload, so my application run in http, but externally is on https. In IIS is bound only http:80. The load balancer use a certificate called `*.mycert.com`

Now I have to require for a client certificate for a specific folder of my application `/Services`, but the certificate is `myPeskyCert` so different from *.mycert.com. This is necessary because I have to respect how the client will call me.

Currenlty I'm following the following answers:

[Can IIS require SSL client certificates without mapping them to a windows user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29040512/can-iis-require-ssl-client-certificates-without-mapping-them-to-a-windows-user/29237456#29237456)

[What is the difference between requiring an SSL cert and accepting an SSL cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383538/what-is-the-difference-between-requiring-an-ssl-cert-and-accepting-an-ssl-cert)

,but in this way my application:

1. I have to do ssl bridging, so I have to bind 443 on the web app
2. in this way **ALL** my application is presented as myPeskyCert

How do I have to handle IIS in order to present my application as *.mycert.com, but ask for myPeskyCert when the folder /Services is requested?

Comment: There is no per page setting I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's non possible, a certificate must refer to the entire site bound.

The solution is the following:

- bound the application to two different url binding
- on the balancer set one certificate or the other with ssloffload on the two different url